# NameError: uninitialized constant when calling my PageObject using Test-Factory gem

Tags: rspec, factory, watir, pageobjects

I have been struggling for a while now with this issue. I looked at too many posts and even tried another similar gem (Page-Object) with the same results.

I seem to be missing a point on how to instantiate an object I guess.

I would appreciate if someone could enlighten me.

Best,

JFF

Here is my script built by following the instructions of the https://github.com/KualiCo/TestFactory:

### Base_Page.rb

```
class MainPage < PageFactory    
  class << self
    def basic_element    
      action(:my_request_is) { |b| b.text_field(name: 'q').set }
      action(:search) { |b| b.button(name: 'btnK').click }
    end
  end
end
```

### search_spec.rb

```
require 'watir'
require 'test-factory'
require './lib/Base_Page'

include Foundry

RSpec.configure do |config|
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

  config.before(:all) { @b = browser }
  config.before(:each) { @b.goto("http://google.com") }   
  config.after(:suite) { browser.close unless browser.nil? }
end

describe 'Search_Page' do
  it 'allows me to search for a DataObject' do
    on_page MyPage do |page|
      page.my_request_is "Hello World"
    end
  end
end
```

### ERROR

```
> Search_Page   allows me to search for a DataObject (FAILED - 1)
> 
> Failures:
> 
>   1) Search_Page allows me to search for a DataObject
>      > Failure/Error:
>      > > on_page MyPage do |page|
>      > > >    page.my_request_is "Hello World"
>      > > end
> 
>      NameError:
>        uninitialized constant MyPage
>      # ./spec/search_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> 
> Finished in 3.37 seconds (files took 7.25 seconds to load) 1 example,
> 1 failure
> 
> Failed examples:
> 
> rspec ./spec/search_spec.rb:18 # Search_Page allows me to search for a
> DataObject
```

Comment: The spec is looking for `MyPage` where as the Base_page.rb file is defining `MainPage`. I think these names need to be the same.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I had tried so many different thing, I guess I combined issues but It looks like I had not done that part right after I simplefied my script which would have help...

Comment: Thanks Justin! I had tried so many different thing, I guess I combined issues but It looks like I had not done that part right after I simplefied my script which would have help... <br/> Now I am running into this error: <br/> undefined method `my_request_is' for nil:NilClass ? Even after adding an element definition (in case it was needed to initializing my page) as <br/>       element(:my_request) { |b| b.text_field(name: 'q') }  <br/> 

      action(:my_request_is) { my_request.set <br/> 
 still doesn't work.

Comment: I have changed my @b to reference @browser and now I have the following: **undefined method `my_request_is' for #<Watir::Browser:0x33f4818>**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- The page class names do not match - MainPage` vs MyPage.
- `on_page` assumes that the browser is stored in `@browser` (not `@b`).
- In the MainPage class, `class << self` is used in base-like page classes to define sections that can be included into specific page classes. Since you are not using a base class at this point, it can be removed.
- The block for defining my_request_is needs to accept the supplied parameter.

Try the following:

```
class MainPage < PageFactory
  action(:my_request_is) { |v, b| b.text_field(name: 'q').set(v) }
  action(:search) { |b| b.button(name: 'btnK').click }
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

  config.before(:each) { @browser = browser }
  config.before(:each) { @browser.goto("http://google.com") }
  config.after(:suite) { browser.close unless browser.nil? }
end

describe 'Search_Page' do
  it 'allows me to search for a DataObject' do
    on_page MainPage do |page|
      page.my_request_is "Hello World"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right Justin! Thanks for helping out! Still could you please explain the last point that I still do not understand: why can't I use .set in action while .click is allowed? Is it because that functionality did not exist at the time of the gem creation?

Comment: I see that the given exemple for the gem uses the .set, so my guess was wrong. But still does not tell me anything more?

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. When I had tried to include `set` in the page object class it wasn't working even though the code suggested it should. However, I tried again and it does work after all. The answer has been updated to use that approach (note the order of parameters for the block).

Comment: Well done Justin, your great answer has been accepted ! I appreciate the solution and the effort! I am trying to get to where I could have find this answer. I looked under the data_factory.rb file of the gem, even if its content seems a little too complicated for now at my level, it does not seem to have that definition I was looking for.

Comment: Just in case someone else looks at this post: action(:my_request_is) { |v, b| b.text_field(name: 'q').set } If there is more than one field, it is better to define the particular one we want to target

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you chose Test-Factory? It seems to no longer be maintained (at least last check-in was 2014). Why not Page-Object (popular) or Watir-Drops (written by one of the Watir maintainers)?

Comment: I looked at the first factory that I had been advised to look at. I only found out about Page-Object yesterday (did not know about Watir-Drops). Maybe I even initially thought that Page-Object was the "method" that Test-Factory gem was based of ?! I obviously did not know where to look at at first. Then yesterday, I had similar issues using Page-Object anyway, so I happened to post on Test-Factory while I could have posted a similar issue using Page-Object but what mattered to me was to get pass it to understand it. I will definitely look at gems that are actively under development.